# Calling JFrame from separate class

Tags: java, class, jframe, visibility

I am using Intellij IDEA 2017. I am learning how to use JFrames, and am trying to create a basic GUI.

I am trying to create two JFrames in separate classes, and call them from the Main class.

What I was trying to do was set the visibility of the two JFrames to false, and then be able to call them in the Main class using something like: "Class1.frame1.setVisibility(true);", but obviously enough that isn't working.

Is there simpler way to do this that works?

Comment: fyi - It's `setVisible`

Comment: If your two classes extends the JFrame class you can write (your_class CAL = new your_class();
CAL.setVisible(true);) in the man method in both classes.

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't instantiating the class at all.

In the main class, you should be doing-

```
new frame1().setVisible(true);
new frame2().setVisible(true);
```